# How to slow down lan for a target ip

Tags: lan

How can i slow down the lan for a specified Ip address? My friend was telling me about this program that will slow down lan, and we were trying to find it. It was used about the year 2000. Thanks

Comment: say whay? why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: QOS Can do rate limiting. How implementation is not so easy.

Comment: @FrankThomas  If you had limited internet and someone was hogging it all downloading stuff.

Comment: if your network switch or router allows it, you may be able to throttle it there. otherwise, there isn't much you can do from your end, without modifying their PC in any way.

Comment: There WAS a program that would do it, Thanks.

Comment: Someone on another computer? You would need to do it at the switch / router. Was this program something like this, was it? http://www.techradar.com/us/news/networking/routers-storage/how-to-build-a-router-based-on-linux-1119526

Comment: Here's a small collection of (more or less) free tools that could help you achieve what you want, though I'm not sure what it is exactly: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/restrict-or-limit-internet-download-and-upload-transfer-speed/ . It's going to take a little bit of time and, in most cases, physical or distant access to the offending machine, to set them up, but it's work a try. Otherwise, if you can remote-control the PC who's hogging your bandwidth, I'd go with QoS as was suggested by several people in this thread, but the PC would have to have Group Policy installed. That rules out Win Home.

Answer (score 0):

This is called IP QOS (quality of service) and might be implemented by the networking devices (routers/switches), at the OS level or even at the service level (application).

Here are examples of OS level IP QOS documentation for [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1453/ipqos-intro-6.html), [Linux](http://diffserv.sourceforge.net/) and [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/135719/way-to-limit-bandwidth-of-programs-on-windows).

Comment: This was actually used with Windows.

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: QOS is prioritizing packets what count is referring to would be closer to Bandwidth throttling. IMO QOS is a much better solution but not sure that's what Count is after

Comment: @50-3 The last link I posted is precisely talking about Bandwidth Throttling through QOS for Windows.

Comment: It's talking about prioritizing voice packets using the inbuilt QOS in windows their is a nice brief on it here http://superuser.com/questions/412456/what-exactly-does-qos-packet-scheduler-do-what-are-particular-real-reasons-to-k

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using windows, If you are willing to pay for the application, you can use netlimiter on the offending computer to limite the bandwidth that it uses: https://www.netlimiter.com/